# Lightweight ETL or database Sync - Sybase to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, etl, sap-ase, symmetricds

I have been doing some investigations into some light weight database Syncing tools to trial.  The initial task we want to perform is a simple data sync from a few tables on a Sybase ASE database (15) to a SQL Server database (2008 R2).  Timing wise, I'd like to keep my options open, but ultimately, I would like to have the ability to sync every minute or less.

I have been looking at SymmetricDS, which at face value seems to do exactly what I want it to.  The drama is I have hit a couple of roadblocks on the Sybase side of things, which is proving to be very frustrating (Jumpmind support are assisting).  It appears that Java has a problem with the default collation we have on our server, being HP-roman8.  Unfortunately, to change this charset is way bigger then this project itself.

I have also started investigating Talend, but have hit a few roadblocks in relation to requiring older versions of drivers for Sybase and downgrading the installed version of Java.

Without having to go to Replication Server, does anyone have any suggestions on a relatively lightweight ETL or database Syncing tool that will do what I want?  The biggest gotcha thus far is Sybase support - I really need something that will seamlessly work without having to hack too much.

Cheers

Comment: sorry, but your question is too broad. could it be narrowed to a more concrete question?

Comment: No probs - yeah, I admit now it was a question asked in frustration...trialling tools that don't work is not fun.

Comment: Sorry - missed my edit window on the comment above.....

I am specifically looking for a tool to data sync between Sybase ASE and SQL server.  It must have good recovery if it goes offline.  I'm also not afraid if the tool uses triggers, but have a preference to not have to add new columns to existing data tables.  From what I have seen, SymmetricDS seems like a good fit - basically, I am after alternatives to that.

Comment: Maybe you Sybase ASE CIS to 'mount' the tables in question, and use triggers to update the remote database?

Comment: SymmetricDS's support of Sybase is pretty good.  Java's support of the roman8 character set is not so much ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct chenson.  I've updated the original question, for sake of posterity!  I have a feeling that this question might not get answered.  At this point I am seeing what I can do with SSIS on the SQL Server side of things, or ultimately we might step up to the plate and go down the SAP replication server path.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of the sync? Have you considered linked servers in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [uniVocity](http://www.univocity.com). It is a Java-based ETL framework that certainly can help you do what you need. You can use any JDBC driver, define your mappings with a few lines of code and have this working faster than a traditional ETL tool.

Have a read through [its tutorial](http://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity-tutorial) and also check out a few sample projects [here](https://github.com/uniVocity)

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: Hope it helps. Please let me know how it goes. Regarding your problems with the hp-roman8 encoding, do you have the charsets.jar library in your classpath? It comes with the JRE, under the lib folder. See the optional files section on [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jrereadme-182762.html).